# Yocto build directories

Tags: linux, yocto

### Yocto build directory:

Need to better understand what directories are automatically created under my `${TMPDIR}/work` and what for.

I cloned poky repository and run a basic build for `core-image-minimal`, just for my exercise.

I got the following directories created under `${TMPDIR}/work`:

```bash
$~/mrv_dev/yocto-training/build/tmp/work$ ls -la
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x   8 barak barak 4.0K Jun 24 07:25 all-poky-linux
drwxr-xr-x  84 barak barak 4.0K Jun 24 07:25 core2-64-poky-linux
drwxr-xr-x  11 barak barak 4.0K Jun 24 08:41 qemux86_64-poky-linux
drwxr-xr-x 145 barak barak 4.0K Jun 24 07:28 x86_64-linux
```

Not sure which is which.

According to Yocto ref manuals, 2 directories are expected:
`${PACKAGE_ARCH}-poky-${TARGET_OS}`
`${MACHINE}-poky-${TARGET_OS}`

### my env values are:

```
$ bitbake -e --dry-run core-image-minimal | grep "^MACHINE="

MACHINE="qemux86-64"

$ bitbake -e --dry-run core-image-minimal | grep "^PACKAGE_ARCH="

PACKAGE_ARCH="qemux86_64"

$ bitbake -e --dry-run core-image-minimal | grep "^PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS="

PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS="x86_64 core2-64"
```

What's expected to be in `core2-64-poky-linux`? is this the `${PACKAGE_ARCH}-poky-${TARGET_OS}` ?
I see here that all recipes are extracted and built under their working directories.

What's expected to be in `qemux86_64-poky-linux`? is this the `${MACHINE}-poky-${TARGET_OS}`?
I see that the rootfs and the final images for `core-image-minimal` are generated here.

What are `x86_64-linux` and `all-poky-linux` direcotires used for?

Will be glad to clarify that.

Thanks,
Barak

Answer (score 0):

- `all-poky-linux` holds the recipes that are architecture-independent, like scripts.
- `x86_64-linux`: used to hold recipes that are built for the build host that are used to build other recipes for the target machine. For more info check this [link](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Technical_FAQ#What_does_.22native.22_mean.3F)
- `qemux86_64-poky-linux`: holds recipes that are machine-specific like `core-image-minimal` as it is an image containing packages and boot/kernel binaries/configuration specific only to `qemux86_64`.
- `core2-64-poky-linux`: holds recipes that are architecture-specific, recipes that runs only on that architecture. It runs on `qemux86_64` machine and can run on other machines that are compatible with that architecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot Talel ! it really helps and clarifies which is which. Especially the the diff between qemux86_64-poky-linux and core2-64-poky-linux folders. Thanks again.

Comment: If that clearly answers your question, selecting it as a correct answer would help.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to start with the **tmp** subfolders first, as they are also getting created during the build:

**buildstats**
is a detailed list of each recipe what "do_" actions has been executed with. including execution time, status, etc.

**cache**
are the components has been built and available for reuse

**deploy**
is the place holder for the produced images as well as packages as well as the license information

**hosttools**
is the storage of the host tools the build system depends on

**log**
is the place holder for the cooker build logs

**pkgdata**
holds the lists of each package (RPM or DEB or IPKG, etc) content

**sstate-control**
is a list of the files produced by each particular recipe "do_" action

**stamps**
hash-stamp of each recipe each "do_" action

**sysroots-components**
is the list of each recipe artifacts to be placed to the target rootfs or to the build rootfs in case of "**native**" (i.e. executed on the build host computer) recipes

**sysroots-uninative**
is the toolchain shared libraries portion of the build rootfs

**work**
is a set of recipe build result artifacts including recipe dependencies

and here is the **work** example list:

**all-poky-linux**
is a platform agnostic **non-executable** recipe artifacts. usually contain graphics, audio, setting files, certificates, etc.

**armv7vet2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi**
is a "**machine**" specific recipe artifacts, built to be execution compatible with processor family usually mentioned in the prefix. example "**armv7vet2hf-neon**"

**usx8001cnl-poky-linux-gnueabi**
is a "**distro**" specific recipe artifacts, built to be executed on the specific hardware design. the name prefix is the actual **PCB** desigh/family of the product. example "**usx8001cnl**"

**x86_64-linux**
is a host tool recipes provided by poky to be built by cooker and to be used instead of the native host tools for the actual cross-compilation yocto builds and are included in the **PATH** variable of the build environment. in example "**x86_64**" prefix means the tools are built for the x86_64 (**AMD64**) architecture to be executed on, but it could be also "**aarch64**" if the host system is **ARM64** based.